# Jacobian of a quaternion rotation wrt the quaternion

Tags: derivatives, quaternions

I am trying to implement an extended Kalman filter which takes a vector as a sensor measurement. To model this I need to rotate the vector to the satellite reference frame using quaternion rotation. For the filter I need to find the Jacobian of my measurement function.

I would like to calculate the Jacobian of some function h which performs a passive quaternion rotation, where q is my quaternion and p is some vector:

$h(q) = q p q^{-1}$

I'd like to find:

$H = \frac{\partial h(q)}{\partial q}$

I'm using unit quaternions in the form $q = [w, \vec{v}]$

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Is "p" is in the form of [0, p] ? Otherwise the dimension don't match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the quaternion multiplication $\circ$ as a matrix-vector product:
$$ q\circ p = Q(q)\cdot p,$$
where
$$ Q(q) = \begin{bmatrix}
q_0 & -q_1 & -q_2 & -q_3 \\
q_1 &  q_0 & -q_3 &  q_2 \\
q_2 &  q_3 &  q_0 & -q_1 \\
q_3 & -q_2 &  q_1 &  q_0 \end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{for}\quad
q = \begin{bmatrix}
q_0 \\
q_1 \\
q_2 \\
q_3 \end{bmatrix}. $$
Likewise, there is a matrix that fulfills $q\circ p = \hat Q(p)\cdot q$ given by
$$ \hat Q(p) = \begin{bmatrix}
p_0 & -p_1 & -p_2 & -p_3 \\
p_1 &  p_0 &  p_3 & -p_2 \\
p_2 & -p_3 &  p_0 &  p_1 \\
p_3 &  p_2 & -p_1 &  p_0 \end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{for}\quad
p = \begin{bmatrix}
p_0 \\
p_1 \\
p_2 \\
p_3 \end{bmatrix}. $$
It is easy to see that for a unit quaternion $q$ it is
$$q^{-1} = \underbrace{\operatorname{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)}_{=:I^*}\cdot q.$$

Now we use the product rule and the above and get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial h(q)}{\partial q}
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial q}(q^*\circ p\circ q^{-1})\big|_{q^*=q} + \frac{\partial}{\partial q}(q\circ p\circ (q^*)^{-1})\big|_{q^*=q} \\
&= Q(q^*\circ p)\cdot I^*\big|_{q^*=q} + \hat Q(p\circ (q^*)^{-1})\big|_{q^*=q} \\
&= Q(q\circ p)\cdot I^* + \hat Q(p\circ q^{-1})
\end{align*}

Notice that, if $h$ is a rotation by a unit quaternion the first row of this matrix will vanish, because the scalar (or real) part of $h(q)$ vanishes, as well.

Comment: I see! Thank you @Wauzl

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about "accepting" answers, thanks again. Unfortunately my rep is a little low for upvoting and downvoting, lucky for you tho! ;)

Comment: Nice answer. A detailed derivation is given in: Lee, Byung-Uk (1991), ["Differentiation with Quaternions, Appendix B"](http://home.ewha.ac.kr/~bulee/quaternion.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

$
\require{enclose}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\rr#1{{#1}^{\small R}}
\def\rrLR#1{\LR{{#1}}^{\small R}}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\mc#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\mq#1{\left[\begin{array}{r|rrr}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\BEvec#1{\begin{Bmatrix}#1\end{Bmatrix}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$An arbitrary quaternion can be represented as
a real vector $(a)$ or matrix $(A)$
$$\eqalign{
a &= \BEvec{a_0\\a_1\\a_2\\a_3} \qif 
A = \mq{
a_0 & -a_1 & -a_2 & -a_3 \\
\hline
a_1 &  a_0 & -a_3 &  a_2 \\
a_2 &  a_3 &  a_0 & -a_1 \\
a_3 & -a_2 &  a_1 &  a_0
} \\
}$$
This allows the quaternion-quaternion product to be replaced by a matrix-vector product.

The order of the product can be **reversed** using a secondary matrix representation which transposes the off-diagonal elements of the bottom left block, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
\rr{A} = \mq{
a_0 & -a_1 & -a_2 & -a_3 \\
\hline
a_1 &  a_0 &  a_3 & -a_2 \\
a_2 & -a_3 &  a_0 &  a_1 \\
a_3 &  a_2 & -a_1 &  a_0
} \\
}$$

$$\eqalign{
f &= a\circ b \qiq f = Ab \\
g &= b\circ a \qiq g = \rr{A}b \\
}$$
First, rewrite the rotation formula to remove the inverse term
$$\eqalign{
h &= q\circ p\circ q^{-1} \qiq
h\circ q &= q\circ p \\
}$$
then calculate the differential,
convert to matrix form,
and isolate the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
dh\circ q &+\; h\circ dq = dq\circ p
  \;+\; \enclose{horizontalstrike}{q\circ dp} \\
\rr{Q}dh &+\; H\,dq = \rr{P}dq \\
\rr{Q}dh &= \LR{\rr{P}-H}dq \\
\grad hq
 &= \LR{\rr{Q}}^{-1}\LR{\rr{P}-H} \\
 &= \rrLR{Q^{-1}} \LR{\rr{P}-H} \\
}$$

### Update

The above gradient does not respect the constraint $\|q\|={\tt1}$.

In order to [satisfy the constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3275502),
one must include a $\c{\rm nullspace\;projector}$
$$\eqalign{
\grad hq &= \LR{\rr{Q}}^{-1}\LR{\rr{P}-H}\CLR{I-qq^T} \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just take the partial derivatives of $h(q)$ with respect to $w$, $i$, $j$ and $k$. That gives you a 3x4 matrix which is the Jacobian.

Comment: Haha... "just" take the derivative!  Did you forget that w is a function of I, just, and k for a normalized quaternion?