# The derivative of a unit vector with respect to itself

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, projection-matrices

I just saw an engineering paper which claims that $$\frac{\partial \hat{\mathbf{x}}}{\partial \hat{\mathbf{x}}} \stackrel{?}{=} -S(\hat{\mathbf{x}})^2 = I - \hat{\mathbf{x}}\hat{\mathbf{x}}^T$$ where $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ is a unit vector, $S(\hat{\mathbf{x}})$ is the [skew symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Cross_product) packing of $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ for use in the cross-product, and I've used the $\stackrel{?}{=}$ symbol to represent the equality I'm calling into question. Is this right? I would have guessed that $$\frac{\partial \hat{\mathbf{x}}}{\partial \hat{\mathbf{x}}} = I$$ just like it is for the vector $\mathbf{x}$, but I'm not sure if the fact that $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ is a constrained vector somehow explains the appearance of the $-\hat{\mathbf{x}}\hat{\mathbf{x}}^T$ term. Any confirmation or correction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\hat{\mathbf{x}} \hat{\mathbf{x}}^T$ is the projection matrix that projects onto the line spanned by $ \hat{\mathbf{x}}$. Hence, $\mathbf I - \hat{\mathbf{x}} \hat{\mathbf{x}}^T$ is the projection matrix that projects onto the space orthogonal to the line, which is a translation of the affine space tangent to the unit Euclidean sphere at $ \hat{\mathbf{x}}$.

Comment: And by translation, you mean specifically that the translation is such that the point at $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ moves to the origin, correct?

Comment: I meant that the tangent hyperplane is translated so that it passes through the origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\x{{\hat x}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Let $\x$ be the direction and $\lambda$ the length of an unconstrained vector $x$.

Calculate the differential of $\x$ as follows
$$\eqalign{
\l^2 &= x^Tx \qiq \l\,d\l = x^Tdx \\
\x &= \l^{-1}x \\
d\x
 &= \c{\l^{-1}dx} - x\l^{-2}d\l \\
 &= \l^{-1}I\,dx - \l^{-3}x\l\,d\l \\
 &= \l^{-1}(I - \l^{-2}xx^T)\,dx \\
 &= \l^{-1}(I - \x\x^T)\,dx \\
}$$
Rearranging the terms yields
$$\eqalign{
d\x
 &= (I - \x\x^T)\,(\c{\l^{-1}dx}) \\
 &= (I - \x\x^T)\,(\c{d\x+x\l^{-2}d\l}) \\
 &= (I - \x\x^T)\,d\x + (I-\x\x^T)\,\x\l^{-1}d\l \\
 &= (I - \x\x^T)\,d\x + (x-\x\x^Tx)\,\l^{-1}d\l \\
 &= (I - \x\x^T)\,d\x + (0)\,\l^{-1}d\l \\
 &= (I - \x\x^T)\,d\x \\
\frac{\partial\x}{\partial\x} &= (I - \x\x^T) \\
}$$
which is the desired result.

Comment: This is great! Would you be willing to add an explanation beyond your proof which gives an intuitive understanding of why it makes sense that we need to subtract $\hat{\mathbf{x}}\hat{\mathbf{x}}^T$ from $I$? Perhaps a geometric analogy?

Comment: I couldn't think of a good geometric argument, but consider this. Since ${\hat x}$ is a unit vector, any change must be orthogonal to its current direction, so ${\hat x}^Td{\hat x}=0$. This means that $d{\hat x}$ must lie in the space of the nullspace projector of ${\hat x}$, i.e. $(I-{\hat x}{\hat x}^+) = (I-{\hat x}{\hat x}^T)$

Comment: That is exactly the intuition I was looking for! Thank you